# How to convert SQL to Linq with SUM calculation

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Can someone help me convert a SQL to Linq? I'm new to Linq and could use some help....

My SQL query string is;

```
SELECT *, Sum(RequisitionQTY*RequisitionPrice) as Total 
FROM partrequisition 
WHERE ReferenceNumber = searchModel.ReferenceNumber 
GROUP BY 'ReferenceNumber'
```

what I have gotten so far is

```
var result = db.partrequisition
    .Where(c => c.ReferenceNumber == searchModel.ReferenceNumber)
    .GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
    .Select( <??> );
```

Not understanding how to do the calculation and build that into the Linq..

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? The result will be a list of sum for each reference numberger

```
var result = db.partrequisition
    .Where(c => c.ReferenceNumber == searchModel.ReferenceNumber)
    .GroupBy(c => c.ReferenceNumber)
    // For each group, calculate the sum
    .Select(g=> g.Sum( item=>item.RequisitionQTY*item.RequisitionPrice ))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you..  I'm getting an error message decimal?' does not contain a definistion for 'SelectMany' and no extention method 'SelectMany' accepting frist argument of type 'decimal' could be found.  The name 'SelectMany'  does not exist in the current context.

Comment: There was a missing ")" after the Sum() call. Try adding it back.

Comment: Thank you again.. Error message Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<decimal?>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PartsManagement.Models.partrequisition>'

Comment: Problem related to DbSet is outside the scope of your original OP. As I said, the result here is a type of List<decimal?>. How to feed the result back to your data base, is worth for another question